# Widget front-end fails to echo as expected from checkbox

Tags: widgets, forms

**Context:** This is my first widget and I am following along with an online tutorial. I am expecting the front-end of the widget to echo some content upon checking a check-box in the back-end form, but rather I am not seeing any content displayed.

**Reference Material:**

- I have attempted to follow along with these two-part tutorials http://www.wpexplorer.com/create-widget-plugin-wordpress/ and http://www.wpexplorer.com/how-to-create-a-widget-plugin-for-wordpress-part-2/ .
- My complete widget file is located here http://pastebin.com/nVTzxiTQ

**screenshots:**

**Back-end looks like this after saving**

[image: Back-end looks like this after saving]

**Front-end looks like this after saving**
[image: Front-end looks like this after saving]

**Question:** Why isn't the act of checking the check-box in the back-end UI resulting in the rendering of the string 'Checkbox is checked' on the front-end, as I expect it to?

Comment: Can you post your widget function's code?

Comment: `$checkbox` variable is `undefined` in your `widget()` function. As you did - `$text = $instance['text']; $textarea = $instance['textarea'];` do the same for `$checkbox = $instance['checkbox']` too.

Comment: I am having trouble formatting the code in large blocks.Right now this is the best I can do, I will edit it later when I can find out how to properly format it.

Comment: @Shazzad your are correct. My failure to define the `$checkbox` variable was the cause of the problem. After defining it as suggested, the widget worked as I exepected. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

on line 49 it seems you have hardcoded in the checkbox value it should actually look like this, it was always going to be true even if it did work as intended:

```
<input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('checkbox'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('checkbox'); ?>" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $checkbox; ?>" <?php checked( '1', $checkbox ); ?> />
```

also after line 81 add this in:

```
$checkbox = $instance['checkbox'];
```

Line numbers are based on what's in pastebin

Comment: thanks. You were correct about Line 81, and after defining it, everything worked as expected. However, regarding your comment about line 49, I am not so sure I follow. After fixing the problem on line 81 the original statement on line 49 worked well.